# One email alert for new documents and another for modified documents

Tags: workflow, document, library

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible.   In a document library I want to send alerts when a document is added to the library and another email when any documents are modified.  So these are two differently worded emails.

I thought if I put document created=modified as my value that if they were the same it would be a new document.  If they were not the same time then it would be modified.  Well, that doesn't work.   Now, I'm trying to figure out how write a workflow to deter the difference?
I know I can have 2 workflows, one workflow when a document is added and another when it is modified, but I was hoping to accomplish this is one workflow.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a Yes/No column to the document library called **CreatedEmailSent** (and update the list content type to hide it so users don't see it in forms). When the document is added, **CreatedEmailSent** will have no value. Your workflow could check the value of this field every time it runs. The first time, when the field has no value (or is set to a default value of No), you could send the created email and update the value of **CreatedEmailSent** to **Yes**. Any time the workflow runs in the future, the field's value would be Yes and your workflow would know to send the modified email instead.

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon.  I noticed that my version number increases from 1.0 when the document is first placed in the library and then when the workflow finishes it is at version 4.0.